# DBeaver SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Asuming the following SQL code in DBeaver 23.2.1

```
with CTE1 as (
    select Col1, Col2, Col3 
    from View1
),
CTE2 as (
    select Col1 
    from View2
),
CTE3 as (
    select Col1 
    from View3
)
```

It produces the following output in DBeaver 23.2.1 but works just fine in MSSMS:

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The last closing parenthesis is marked as syntax error. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Your query isn't complete, add a  SELECT at the end.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You should add it as an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `WITH`clause isn't a complete query, you have to `SELECT` too. Something like

```
with CTE1 as (
    select Col1, Col2, Col3 
    from View1
),
CTE2 as (
    select Col1 
    from View2
),
CTE3 as (
    select Col1 
    from View3
)
select ...
from CTE1 ...
```